Error for listener and Response<ByteArray> with Android Volley
In the below code I am receiving a ByteArray object as a response. Now I want to download the file and preview the file.
For that I had created custom request class, but it is giving two errors. The code below contains listener and Response<ByteArray> as errors:
ByteArrayRequest.kt:
class ByteArrayRequest(
    context: Context,
    fileName: String,
    method: Int,
    url: String,
    jsonRequest: JSONObject?,
    listener: Response.Listener<Unit>, // or custom listener with downloaded file
    errorListener: Response.ErrorListener,
) : JsonObjectRequest(method, url, jsonRequest, listener, errorListener) {
    private val headers: MutableMap<String, String> = HashMap()
    private val context = context
    private val fileName = fileName

    fun addHeader(key: String, value: String) {
        headers[key] = value
    }

    override fun parseNetworkResponse(response: NetworkResponse): Response<ByteArray> {
        val data = response.data
        if (checkWriteExternalStoragePermission()) {
            val file = File(context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), fileName)
            try {
                FileOutputStream(file).use { output ->
                    output.write(data)
                }
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                // Handle IO exception
                return Response.error(VolleyError(e))
            }
            Response.success(Unit, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response))

        } else {
            // Handle permission denied case
            return Response.error(VolleyError(Exception("Storage permission denied")))
        }
    }

    private fun checkWriteExternalStoragePermission(): Boolean {
        return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            context,
            android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    }

    override fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> {
        return headers
    }
}

Activity:
fun submitdata(url: String) {
    //new HttpsTrustManager().allowAllSSL();progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    val js = JSONObject()
    try {
        js.put("year", financialyear!!.selectedItem.toString().toInt())
        js.put("month", month!!.selectedItem.toString().toInt())
        js.put("emp_number", emp_num)
        Log.d("volley","js:${js}")
    } catch (e: JSONException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    val byteArrayRequest = ByteArrayRequest(
        context = applicationContext,
        fileName = "report.pdf",
        method = Request.Method.POST,
        url = url,
        jsonRequest = js,
        listener = {
            // Handle the byte array response here
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "File downloaded to: ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        },
        errorListener = { error ->
            Log.d("volley","Error:${error.message}")
        },
    )
    byteArrayRequest.retryPolicy = DefaultRetryPolicy(
        100000,
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT
    )
    byteArrayRequest.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + SharedPrefrence.getApitoken(applicationContext))
    byteArrayRequest.addHeader("x-api-key", SharedPrefrence.getApikey(applicationContext)!!)

    // Add the request to a request queue
    val requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(applicationContext)
    requestQueue.add(byteArrayRequest)
}

